# Use an Android TextView as a "drawable" while still maintaining editing capabilities

Tags: android, overlay, drawable, osmdroid

I am creating an Android public transportation application that uses Open Street Map. The problem is - there are so many stations that I need to divide them into areas of the city, each area having a few hundreds of them. The plan is to display only the individual bus stations that are relevant to that area, while keeping the others hidden in their groups, in order to save memory, CPU and make the interface fluent.

I want to be able to display the number of stations in an area when the map is zoomed out after a certain point, and I have already implemented the behavior of this. The problem is - I don't know how to display the number of stations as a "text drawable".

I have implemented one text view that is over the map, containing the total number of the bus stations in the center of the city, when you enter the application, and it works well. However, the `TextView` that does this is part of the `RelativeLayout` of the `MapActivity` - that's not what I want - I want the `TextView` to be anchored into the map. Right now, if you scroll the map, the `TextView` simply sits in the middle of the screen, since it's part of the `RelativeLayout`, and not part of the actual map, as an item on the map.

Here's how my `MapActivity` looks like, in terms of its layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_activity_map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/map_activity_station_number_textview"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_view_circle"
    android:text="10"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the drawable used as a background by the `TextView` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/applicationBackground"/>

<stroke
    android:width="4dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white"/>

<corners
    android:radius="50dp"/>

</shape>
```

This works and creates a `TextView` in the center of the screen, being populated with the total number of bus stations in the city.

Again, the problem is that I want to create several of these, and they must be fixed on the map. We can do this as "map items". The problem is, in order to be a map item, you have to be a drawable and not a `TextView`.

Here's how that looks like:

```
//set the icon for the bus station group (in this case, the text in the circle with the number of stations)
    busStationDrawableOverlay = this.getDrawable(R.drawable.bus_station_small);

for (GeoPoint busStationGroup : busStationGroupList){
    //create the overlay that will appear on the map as the station icon
    OverlayItem busStationGroupItem = new OverlayItem(null, null, busStationGroup);
    //set the bus station icon as the busStationDrawableOverlay the we declared above (and set the right icon)
    busStationGroupItem.setMarker(busStationDrawableOverlay);
    //add the station to the stationLocation list so it can be displayed on the map
    busStationGroupLocation.add(busStationGroupItem);
}
```

The problem with this is that it only works with a drawable. So, if I use an icon, I do get the "anchoring on the map" behavior. I need to be able to do the same with the `TextView`, so that I can actually write in it the number of stations in that area.

Any idea how to do that? How can I implement a `TextView` as a "Drawable" and still be able to edit it and control it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Marker overlay, using a nearly-hidden-feature: when a Marker has no icon but a title, this title can be drawn as a text. This way:

```
Marker.ENABLE_TEXT_LABELS_WHEN_NO_IMAGE = true; //necessary to activate this behaviour. 

myMarker.setTitle("The text I want to draw);
myMarker.setIcon(null);
```

You can adjust the look&feel with: setTextLabelBackgroundColor, setTextLabelForegroundColor, setTextLabelForegroundColor.

You will have to call myMarker.setIcon(null) everytime you change the marker title.

If you don't like the result, a simple alternative is to use a Marker, building its icon drawable from your text every time your text changes. 
Look at Marker.setIcon source code, this will give you everything you need to do something similar yourself.